# when I use this input validation loop even if the answer is right it loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use this input validation loop even if the answer is right it loops

```
def HouseVer():
    my_house=""
    while my_house !="green" and my_house !="red" and my_house !="purple" and  my_house !="yellow":
        my_house=input("Which house do you live in?, green, red, purple, or yellow ")

    return my_house
HouseVer()
```

Comment: Works fine for me... Are you sure you pasted the right piece of code?

Comment: side note: more pythonic (and faster): `while my_house not in set("green", "red", "purple", "yellow"): ...`

Comment: @hiro Or less code. `not in {"green", "red", "purple", "yellow"}`

Comment: @cricket_007: oh, sure! i keep writing `set` instead of brackets. no idea why. i'll remember your comment next time hopefully... thanks!

Comment: Can you try `my_house=input("Wich house do you live in?, green, red, purple, or yellow ").strip()`

Answer (score 0):

If you really only enter `green` for example, it should work - at least it does for me. But to be safe, you could do some normalizing on the input (I also reformatted your code a bit to be more readable):

```py
def HouseVer():
    house_color = None
    while house_color not in ("green", "red", "purple", "yellow"):
        house_color = input("Enter the color of your house (green, red, purple, or yellow): ").strip().lower()

    return house_color

HouseVer()
```

If this still does not work, you can see which value your loop condition gets with the following code:

```py
def HouseVer():
    house_color = None
    while house_color not in ("green", "red", "purple", "yellow"):
        if house_color != None: # user entered invalid input if != None
            print(f"Invalid input '{house_color}' - try again !") # using f-string
        
        house_color = input("Enter the color of your house (green, red, purple, or yellow): ").strip().lower()

    return house_color

HouseVer()
```

It would be a good idea to show such messages to the user anyways.